# BizTalk 2010 XLang PersistenceException error Persisting State to the Database

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have an odd BizTalk issue that only occurs in the Production environment.  It started over the weekend.  The error message from Event Viewer is at the end of this post.

I researched this online and all the possible solutions proposed by the gurus did not do the trick.  On a lark, I exported the MSI from that Production BizTalk server and installed that MSI on a development machine.  That Development BizTalk worked beautifully with the same file against a different SQL Server database (development DB).

Next, I went ahead and uninstalled and deleted that BizTalk application from the Production BizTalk server and re-imported & re-installed the same MSI (that was used on the aforementioned Development BizTalk machine).  The same error occurred.

That leads me to ask what is probably a stupid question... would rebooting a production SQL Server (which more or less is verboten unless there are critical upgrades that need to be applied) solve this?   The reason I ask this is because if the exact same MSI from the production BizTalk server worked elsewhere, but does not work on that one production BizTalk server.

Any ideas?   Without further ado, here's the error message.

> xlang/s engine event log entry: Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'Xpress.BizTalk.P837.EDI_837P_5010_to_WorkTable_And_4010(dee9b36c-4d44-20a1-01b0-efc184ec3efb)'.
>
> The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated.
>
> If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: d768edda-35ba-4bb1-a57d-347cc54ddf49
>
> Shape name: Send 837P 4010
>
> ShapeId: dcb098dc-9c6b-41b0-8511-c9a250de52b2
>
> Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 94
>
> Inner exception: Exception occurred when persisting state to the database.
>
> Exception type: PersistenceException
>
> Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
>   Target Site: Void Commit()
>
> The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured
>
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXXlangStore.Commit()
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.Persist(Boolean dehydrate, Context ctx, Boolean idleRequired, Boolean finalPersist, Boolean bypassCommit, Boolean terminate)
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ServiceContext.PendingCommit(Boolean ignore, XMessage msg)
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.ExceptionHandlingContext.PendingCommit(Boolean ignoreCommit, XMessage msg)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.XLANGs.BTXEngine.BTXPortBase.SendMessage(Int32 iOperation, XLANGMessage msg, Correlation[] initCorrelations, Correlation[] followCorrelations, Context cxt, Segment seg, ActivityFlags flags)
>      at Xpress.BizTalk.P837.EDI_837P_5010_to_WorkTable_And_4010.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
>      at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)
>
> Additional error information:
>
> A batch item failed persistence Item-ID 433c9f39-f2c7-4ac3-ae29-32b990b20bdd OperationType MAIO_CommitBatch Status -1061151992 ErrorInfo The operation could not be performed because the message on which it was acting was not found in the database. .

Comment: Were any changes made on the weekend?  What are the solutions you tried? A persistence error usually occurs if the message that you are trying to publish to the message box does not match the any of the subscriptions on the Orchestration and Send Port that are enlisted.  Have you checked that the context properties on the message match the subscription of the port/orchestration? That additional error is odd, a search brings up  a hotfix for BizTalk 2004 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814041/en-gb  so not relevant I hope.

Comment: It is very unlikely restarting SQL Server would correct this.  Does this happen on every message of just intermittently?  With the same message or random ones?

Comment: Well, rebooting both the SQL Server and BIzTalk server did the trick.  Go figure.

Comment: Dijkgraaf, that's the problem.  BizTalk was working just perfectly fine prior to the weekend.  We did not even deploy an update to production Biztalk at all.   

Something changed between last Friday and Tuesday.  Rebooting both SQL Server and BizTalk Server did the trick, as strange as that may sound.

Comment: Very strange.  Good that it resolved.